# How is feedback process done after submitting an article to arXiv?

Tags: peer-review, arxiv

Another arXiv related question...

In several posts I have seen people talking about [getting feedback](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26820/can-posting-to-arxiv-ruin-your-reputation?noredirect=1&lq=1) after submitting article to arXiv

I have never submitted anything to arXiv before, so I have no clue how this is done. Is this just an informal procedure whereby other researchers in your field email you about your article?

Or is there a formal feedback process submitted through arXiv? Is this for available for public viewing or discussion?

How exactly is this done? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official protocol or formal procedure. Here is how I handle it.

I skim the arxiv submission in my fields of interest every day (headlines and abstracts). Every few days I find some things that I read in greater detail and if it happens that I find something that I'd like to discuss with the authors, I write a joint email to all of them. Could be a question for clarification, a hint for further reading or something like "look here, I've done something related". Once in while I take the time to write a blog post for some article and then it sometimes (rarely) happens that one of the authors comments on my blog.